# NodeJs Cannot find custom native module (C++ and node-addon-api)

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, node-gyp, node-addon-api

I built my own NodeJs Module with node-addon-api in C++ and now I want to use it in an electron.js app. But unfortunetly stuck with can not find module error.

My project structure is like the following:

```
/
  /build
    /Release
      myAddon.node
  /node_modules
  binding.gyp
  index.js
  index.html
  package.json
  package-lock.json
```

The node-gyp build runs without failures and the module is in the /build/Release folder.

Now I want to load the module in my index.js file with

```
const myAddon = require('./build/Release/myAddon.node)
```

And when I start the app it fails with

```
Error: Cannot find module 

\\?\Path\To\MyProject\build\Release\myAddon.node
```

The path in the error message is correct and the .node file is there. Is there any further configuration or setting which I have forgotten?

Here is the output with the bindings addon:

```
 App threw an error during load
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
```

And then there is a list with some folders it has tried to find it. But none of these folders exists in my project.

Comment: Try to use [bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bindings) to get a better error log.

Comment: I have updatet the question with the output

Comment: In the file tree the file name is called myNodeAddon.node, but in the require line you are referring to it as myAddon.node, maybe it is just that typo.

Comment: No, this is not the Problem. These example has not the real names of the files. I will change this, sorry.

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm having a same issue but in my case, it works for dev version. however, it threw module not found exception in the production build. Let me know if you have any workaround.

Comment: No, I have no solution for the problem yet. I only had a little discussion here https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2207. But there is also no solution.